# How to make changes to egress rules for AWS security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-security-group, outbound

I have a lambda and my script in running on it, it's connecting to a database, I have attached a security group to this lambda, the outbound rules is allow all Protocol and all ports, it seems a bit too permissive, but I'm not sure how to change it to the setting I need, is there any suggestions?

How should I narrow down the permission range and my lambda will also work? Or is it safe to keep it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [security_groups](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#security_groups) in `egress` to limit outgoing traffic to the SG of your database:

```
egress {
    from_port   = 0
    protocol    = -1
    to_port     = 0
    security_groups = [database_security_group_id]
  }
```

Comment: and what's the meaning of those 0,-1,0?

Comment: I just tried and apparently ```security_group``` is not a valid parameter, it gave me error ```Error: Incorrect attribute value type```

Comment: @Cecilia please read the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#egress). It clearly explains what the values mean. You will get answers quicker that way.

Comment: @Cecilia Can you update the question with exactly how you are modify the egress rule now?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I've solved this problem, thanks for the insight, `security_groups` isn't a valid parameter for egress rule, we still need to use `cidr_blocks=xxx`, I just specified the port range and protocol to use the ones I'm using for my db, so that it won't allow other port and protocol to access.

Comment: @Cecilia Hi. According to [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#security_groups), `security_groups` is valid in `egress`.? What error messages did you get?